# "is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" between internal network Windows servers

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

We have 2 internal (intranet) Windows server on our network, only available to the local network. On `server1` Spark is installed, where we can query Jabber information like so:

```
http://server1/plugins/presence/status?jid=username@jabbersrv&type=text
```

On `server2` Spiceworks is installed, and I wrote a plugin to query that Jabber status like so:

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://server1/plugins/presence/status?jid=username@jabbersrv&type=text", false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
statusStr = xmlHttp.responseText;
```

But this code (on `server2`) is returning an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server1/plugins/presence/status?jid=username@jabbersrv&type=text. Origin https://server2 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Why does this not work? I have some VB.net code that accomplishes this fine in the same environment:

```
Dim jbrStatus As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim userStatus As String = jbrStatus.DownloadString("http://server1/plugins/presence/status?jid=username@jabbersrv&type=text")
```

Neither are running Apache or the sort that I'm aware of, although Openfire is on `server1`. Should these 2 servers not inherently trust each other since they are internal (on the same domain)? What would be the best way of getting this working on a Windows domain & Windows servers?

I have tried adding server2 domain server as local admin on server1, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether they're on the same network. If they have different domain names, XMLHttpRequests won't work by default. You'll need the server to send back certain headers, for [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Note that this will only work on more recent browsers.

Comment: They're both on the same domain, is that relevant?

Comment: The whole domain names have to match (not just the last two parts). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests

Comment: Sorry, I meant Windows domain.

Comment: That won't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with Same-origin policy

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

> The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same
>   site to access each other's methods and properties with no specific
>   restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and properties
>   across pages on different sites.

server1 / server2 are considered different domains, even though on the same network.